# How can I use System.Net.Http.HttpClient instead of WebRequest?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have made a website to check if it is still working or not, on my machine it works normally but when I publish it on the server, it gives error 500. I looked at the article on microsoft and saw "Don't use WebRequest or its derived classes for new development. Instead, use the System.Net.Http.HttpClient class."
But I don't know how to use that method. How do I change the method of my website?
And this is my code:

```
public static bool WebRequestTest(string url)
{
    try
    {
        System.Net.WebRequest myRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url);
        System.Net.WebResponse myResponse = myRequest.GetResponse();
    }
    catch (System.Net.WebException)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

And this is my error:

> Server Error in '/' Application. Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined. Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.

Comment: What's the actual error message? Error 500 can be anything and not necessarily because of using WebRequest.

Comment: There are *many* examples to be found online, you're very much encouraged to make an attempt.  Though if the server you're requesting is returning a 500 response, I don't see how using a different class to make the request is expected to change that.  It sounds like you're randomly guessing instead of diagnosing the cause of the error.  Microsoft may be recommending newer things, but they haven't *sabotaged* the `WebRequest` class.  It still successfully does exactly what it's always done.

Comment: @CharlesHan Thanks for your comment. I added the error description to my question.

Comment: @David Thanks for your comment. I tried changing that method to checking with DNS and it had no problems so I thought maybe the WebRequest method is not working. Maybe I was wrong in assuming it was an error from that method.

Comment: What's the URL you sent to this call?

Comment: @CharlesHan I sent url: https:// google.com

Comment: You have a space between // and google, so remove the space, `https://google.com`

Comment: @CharlesHan I added a space in the middle because if I don't insert a space it returns like this https://google.com. Actually, there are no spaces in my url string.

Comment: tried it on my machine, and it works fine for my project.

Comment: @CharlesHan It also works fine on my pc but when I was public to hosting it doesn't work :(

Comment: @Ultron: Where/how *specifically* are you observing this URL value?  Is this based on specific debugging, or just an assumption?

Answer (score 0):

You can do like below code

```
public static async Task<bool> WebRequestTest(string url)
{
try
{
   using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {

            var result = await client.GetAsync(url);
            HttpStatusCode httpStatusCode= result.StatusCode;
        }
  
   
}
catch (System.Net.WebException)
{
    return false;
}
return true;
}
```

You will get lot of example about Httpclient.